# How to generate same wsdl in Spring-ws

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I'm migrating a system to Java using Spring 4, and I need to create some Soap Services base on a WSDL.

My problem is that the WSDL my client produces **doesn't have any request or response (complextype) tag inside the schema** and Spring-ws for default does not produce any message (service) in the wsdl using the original schema because it looks for Resquest and Response suffix inside the schema's values.

Now my client's WSDL look like this:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://mypackage.com/myService"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://mypackage.com/myService"
                  targetNamespace="http://mypackage.com/myService">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://mypackage.com/myService"
                xmlns:hr="http://mypackage.com/myService">
            <element name="element1" type="string"/>
            <element name="element2" type="string"/>
            <element name="elementReturn1" type="string"/>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="service1Request">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:element1" name="element1"/>
        <wsdl:part element="tns:element2" name="element2"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="service1Response">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:elementReturn1" name="elementReturn1"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="myService">
        <wsdl:operation name="service1">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:service1Request" name="service1Request"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:service1Response" name="service1Response"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="myServiceSoap11" type="tns:myService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="service1">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="service1Request">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="service1Response">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="myService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:myServiceSoap11" name="myServiceSoap11">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:7001/mydomain/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And the WSDL spring-ws generated by default with this schema look like this:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://mypackage.com/myService"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://mypackage.com/myService"
                  targetNamespace="http://mypackage.com/myService">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://mypackage.com/myService"
                xmlns:hr="http://mypackage.com/myService">
            <element name="element1" type="string"/>
            <element name="element2" type="string"/>
            <element name="elementReturn1" type="string"/>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:portType name="myService"></wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="myServiceSoap11" type="tns:myService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="myService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:myServiceSoap11" name="myServiceSoap11">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:7001/mydomain/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

As you can noticed the wsdl spring-ws generated doesn't produce any message what it means there's no service to consume.

**Could you tell me how do I tell Spring-ws to make soap message (requests and responses) without specifying in the schema so I can build same wsdl structure?**

In order to build same web service I added manually Request and Response tag to my schema and the wsdl I generated look like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://mypackage.com/myService" 
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                  xmlns:tns="http://mypackage.com/myService" 
                  targetNamespace="http://mypackage.com/myService">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://mypackage.com/myService"
                xmlns:hr="http://mypackage.com/myService">
            <element name="service1Request">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element ref="hr:element1"/>
                        <element ref="hr:element2"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="service1Response">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element ref="hr:elementReturn1"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>

            <element name="element1" type="string"/>
            <element name="element2" type="string"/>
            <element name="elementReturn1" type="string"/>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="service1Request">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:service1Request" name="service1Request"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="service1Response">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:service1Response" name="service1Response"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="myService">
        <wsdl:operation name="service1">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:service1Request" name="service1Request"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:service1Response" name="service1Response"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="myServiceSoap11" type="tns:myService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="service1">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="service1Request">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="service1Response">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="myService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:myServiceSoap11" name="myServiceSoap11">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:7001/mydomain/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In terms of consuming one of this service the input for the first one (my client's) would be something like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:act="http://mypackage.com/myService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <act:element1>A</act:element1>
       <act:element2>B</act:element2>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

While spring-ws look like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:act="http://mypackage.com/myService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <act:service1Request>
         <act:element1>A</act:element1>
         <act:element2>B</act:element2>
      </act:service1Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My **web.xml** is this:

```
<web-app  version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring3 MVC Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:MyContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And I have a **spring-ws-servlet.xml** as well that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd">

    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>

    <bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
        <property name="schema" ref="mySchema"/>
        <property name="portTypeName" value="myService"/>
        <property name="locationUri" value="/"/>
        <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://mypackage.com/myService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySchema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
        <property name="xsd" value="classpath:schemas/mySchema.xsd"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**PD: I'm working with Weblogic that's why I use XML configuration over Java code for Spring.**

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I did what you suggested and I could deploy my wsdl as I was expecting, but now I can match my Endpoint

My project have the next files:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app  version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring4 Soap</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:SpringConfig.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-ws-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd">

    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.myService"/>

    <bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
        <property name="wsdl" value="classpath:example.wsdl" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and **ServiceEnpoint**

```
@Endpoint
public class ServiceEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mypackage.com/myService";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "service1Request")
    @ResponsePayload
    public String getEstadoDocRequest(String element1,
                                      String element2) {
        return  element1 + " " + element2;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to test my service through SoapUI I got the next error:

**ADVERTENCIA: No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://mypackage.com/myService}element1]
<27-04-2016 10:50:28 Hora de Chile>    http://mypackage.com/myService}element1]>**

As you can noticed Spring is looking for a request and it doesn't know that element1 is an element of request1.

How can I tell Spring which is the request so it can match my request with my endpoint

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the "client" in your description is bit misleading. Did you try using a static wsdl definition (i.e. SimpleWsdl11Definition constructor)?

Comment: I Edit my question using SimpleWsdl11Definition as you suggested and now I have a different problem. Thanks in advanced for your help

Comment: If you are able to change the wsdl I will suggest adding a soap action ahd then instead of targeting the method with @PayLoad, you could use the @SoapAction(value="thenamespace/thesoapAction". Last but not least, you cannot convert directly your request to java, you need to describe it using a marshaller.

Comment: Sorry I haven't being able to test what your suggest, I've been busy working in some other stuff, actually the idea is not to change the wsdl because I want to replicate the same so my client's clients doesn't have to change anything to connect with my services...